# How to scrape an attribute value from script type text on a website after first pressing a button using python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm learning python and web scraping and for this project I'm trying to find the "url" attribute from
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpllJ.png). I am using selenium for the rest of the script but am having trouble finding the data using find_elements, with class name, xpath, css selector, etc.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains


# Set up the Chrome driver and maximize the window
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")

service = Service('C:\windows\chromedriver.exe')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=service)
company = 'nvidia-corp'

# Navigate to the URL
url = f"https://ads.tiktok.com/business/creativecenter/hashtag/example/pc/en?countryCode=US&period=7"
driver.get(url)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
# Find the button element using the full XPath
button_xpath = '//*[@id="trendHashtagDetail"]/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/div/button[2]'
button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, button_xpath)))

# Click the button 10 times
for i in range(10):
    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    actions.move_to_element(button).click().perform()

#Find all the url attributes and save/print them
```

I've tried requests, json, bs4, and selenium find elements all results in errors with finding the elements so I must be doing something wrong. Hopefully I described the issue well enough to be understood and any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Screenshots of the UI are great, screenshots of code or HTML are not. Please read why [a screenshot of code/HTML is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the HTML as text and properly format it instead.

Answer (score 1):

This was not as straightforward as I originally thought... there were several issues I ran into.

1. The main problem you were having is that EACH of the 5 tok previews on the page were inside an IFRAME. In Selenium, you need to switch the context into the IFRAME, get what you need, and then switch back out of the context. You need to do this each time you grab the url from a tok.
2. The next problem I ran into was that the JSON text returned from the SCRIPT tag was escaped so it had to be `unescaped`.
3. Once I had the unescaped JSON text, we need to parse the JSON.
4. The next problem I ran into was that only 5 of the ~50 toks on the page were visible at a time in the carousel. So I added a loop from 0 to 4 to get the 5 visible toks.
5. The last problem was how to stop the script. I finalized on waiting until the Next button becomes disabled. So, each time the inner loop completes, if the Next button is disabled we `exit()`.

The final code

```
import json
from html import unescape

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

# Set up the Chrome driver and maximize the window
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()

# Navigate to the URL
url = "https://ads.tiktok.com/business/creativecenter/hashtag/example/pc/en?countryCode=US&period=7"
driver.get(url)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
while True:
    for i in range(0, 5):
        iframes = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_any_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "section > iframe")))
        wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(iframes[i]))
        script = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#embed-video-container > script")
        url = json.loads(unescape(script.get_attribute("innerHTML")))["url"]
        print(url)
        driver.switch_to.default_content()

    next = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[class*='right']:not([class*='disabled'])")
    if next:
        next[0].click()
    else:
        exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the text from the script element then parse it as JSON:

```
import json
#...
elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("script[type='application/ld+json']")
jsontext = json.loads(elem.get_attribute("innerHTML"))
```

then next you would get URL from JSON

```
url = jsontext["url"]
```

Kudos to the [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67655528/20155810).

Comment: Hey I tried

`elem = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "script[type='application/ld+json']")
jsontext = json.loads(elem.get_attribute("innerHTML"))
url = jsontext["url"]
print(url)`

and get
``
---> 40 url = jsontext["url"]

KeyError: 'url'
``

Comment: @Esenomo could you please print the jsontext var by itself and let me know what you get

Comment: {'@context': 'https://schema.org/', '@type': 'BreadcrumbList', 'itemListElement': [{'@type': 'ListItem', 'position': 1, 'name': 'Homepage', 'item': 'https://ads.tiktok.com/business/creativecenter/pc/en'}, {'@type': 'ListItem', 'position': 2, 'name': 'Trend Hashtag', 'item': 'https://ads.tiktok.com/business/creativecenter/inspiration/popular/hashtag/pc/en'}, {'@type': 'ListItem', 'position': 3, 'name': 'example'}]}

Comment: My guess is that there is more than one of these `<script>` blocks on the page and your locator isn't specific enough so you're just getting the first one which isn't the correct one. I would try `elem = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#embed-video-container > script")`. If that doesn't work, try `elem = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#main > #embed-video-container > script")`.

Comment: @Esenomo if you have trouble finding the right selector in future you can use CTRL+F in the inspector elements panel and put in your selector to see the amount of matches it has or if the selector even works

Comment: I finally worked my way through all the issues. Your answer helped solve one of them. See my answer for all the details.